Apache2 not working after upgrade to 24.04
I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 last week. My linux box is used primarily as a email server and a webserver. There  is only one domain remaining. I deleted a second domain that was no longer needed. I didn't notice that Apache2 was working fire several days due to the browser cache.
I'm using LetsEncrypt for my SSL certs.
When I check status, I get this result. It appears Apache2 is being deactivated,

apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server    Loaded: loaded
(/usr/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
 Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2024-06-21 12:47:58 CDT; 3h 35min ago    Duration: 2d 22h 44min 319ms
   Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
Process: 261192 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 261195 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful-stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    CPU: 44ms Jun 21 12:47:58 Ares systemd[1]: Starting apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server... Jun 21 12:47:58 Ares

apachectl[261194]: httpd (pid 259133) already running Jun 21 12:47:58
Ares systemd[1]: apache2.service: Deactivated successfully. Jun 21
12:47:58 Ares systemd[1]: Started apache2.service - The Apache HTTP
Server.*

Update. 06-22-2024
The contents of the error.log is zero. It's empty. However, I did a apache2ctl start...and that worked when it didn't yesterday. Best of my memory, I have NOT changed anything except to logout yesterday and login today.
Thank you for your time.

There should be a more detailed reason that explains why Apache isn’t working in the /var/log/apache/error.log file

Check all files in your /var/log/apache/, The error.log file rotates daily. So, what you are looking for can be in error.log.1 or error.log.2.gz or error.log.3.gz...

In error.log.1 there was an entry that said apache2 had an unclean shutdown. No apparent cause. Several attempts to start after the 'deactivation' flagged errors that said apache2 was already running. Restart did no correct the error.
However, sudo systemctl start apache2 worked and the apache2 is now running. No idea what the deactivation was caused by. It appears that while apache2 was deactivated, it was still running.
